# Inquiries on Strong Diffie-Hellman assumption

Tags: diffie-hellman, hardness-assumptions

According to the SDH assumption, it is hard for an adversary to output a pair $(c,g_1^{\frac{1}{c+\alpha}})$ given a $q+2$ tuple ($g_1$,$g_2$,$g_2^{\alpha}$, ...,$g_2^{{\alpha}^q}$)

Now, consider $g_1$,$g_2$,$g_2^{\alpha}$, $c_1$, and $c_2$ is given to an adversary:

1- How is it hard to calculate $g_1^{\frac{1}{c_1+\alpha}}$ and $g_1^{\frac{1}{c_2+\alpha}}$? Is it still under the hardness of SDH?

2- How is it hard to calculate $g_1^{\frac{1}{c_k+\alpha}}$ where $c_k \ne c_1$ and $c_k \ne c_2$?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptogrsphy.se. What is the origin of this question?

Comment: Thanks. Actually, It is related to the BBS short group signature.

Comment: If you solve 1 then you can solve SHD, the converse is not obvious. So 1 is harder than SDH given that $q >1$

Comment: Do you have an idea what is the name of this problem? Is it mentioned and proven before as hard problem? Thanks

Comment: It is important how you asked the question. Now, your question has more details than you first asked. It was like a HW question so that some people didn't look and answer. My advice, is [edit]  your question to include ( or delete this question and ask a new one with ) full details, where did you see this, what do you want. It seems that you are looking for a reference request and this is valid and we have a tag for that, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kelalaka. I will edit the question a little bit to be clear that this is a variation of SDH.